# FullSimplify not giving me a physically useful answer for Mott scattering

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, physics, conditional

I am using *Mathematica* to find the cross-section for Mott scattering over an extended target. I evaluated

```
FullSimplify[With[{A = 1/137, B = 1, p = 100}, Integrate[Integrate[
π A^2 (1 - (B^2) (Sin[x/2])^2) (Sin[x])/(2 (p^2) (B^2) (Sin[x/2])^4),
{x, ArcTan[(600 - z), 155], ArcTan[(100 - z), 155]}], {z, 0, 750}]]/700]
```

and got

> ```
> Integrate[
>   ConditionalExpression[(1/187690000)*Pi*
>     (Csc[(1/2)*ArcTan[610 - z, 155]]^2 + 2*(1/(-1 + Cos[ArcTan[110 - z, 155]]) + 
>        Log[Csc[(1/2)*ArcTan[110 - z, 155]]*Sin[(1/2)*ArcTan[610 - z, 155]]])), 
>     Sin[(1/2)*ArcTan[110 - z, 155]] >= 0 && 
>     Sin[(1/2)*ArcTan[610 - z, 155]] >= 0 && 
>    ((Re[ArcTan[610 - z, 155]/(ArcTan[110 - z, 155] - ArcTan[610 - z, 155])] >= 0 && 
>     ArcTan[610 - z, 155]/(ArcTan[110 - z, 155] - ArcTan[610 - z, 155]) != 0) || 
>     NotElement[
>       ArcTan[610 - z, 155]/(ArcTan[110 - z, 155] - ArcTan[610 - z, 155]), 
>       Reals] || 
>     Re[ArcTan[610 - z, 155]/(ArcTan[110 - z, 155] - ArcTan[610 - z, 
>       155])] <= -1)], 
>   {z, 10, 760}]
> ```

I have verified for myself that these conditions are all met. Moreover, as this is a physical situation, I should get a physical answer. What more do I need to tell *Mathematica* to get something physically useful?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: What version are you running? I'm not able to reproduce it. Also, `Integrate`, like all functions that accept iterators, e.g. `Table`, etc., allows you to specify them in one function call, i.e. `Integrate[..., {z, ...}, {x, ...}...]`, which allows internal simplifications and other speed ups to be invoked. And, it's easier to write.

Comment: I think you want this: `With[{A=1/137,B=1,p=100},NIntegrate[\[Pi] A^2 (1-(B^2) (Sin[x/2])^2) (Sin[x])/(2 (p^2) (B^2) (Sin[x/2])^4),{z,0,750},{x,ArcTan[(600-z),155],ArcTan[(100-z),155]}]]/700` I.e., use `NIntegrate` and follow the advice of @rcollyer. Note the order of integration variables (outermost first).

Comment: Student Version 8.0.4.0 on a Mac OS X

Comment: Running the `Integrate` and `NIntegrate` versions on both 8.0.1 and recent sources, I get identical results between the two versions. So, I suspect it is getting hung up on the nesting you're using. BTW, running the `Integrate` result through `N` gives the same result as `NIntegrate`, but it takes much, much longer. Go the `NIntegrate` route.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is as follows.  First note that `0 <ArcTan[(600 - z), 155] < ArcTan[(100 - z), 155] < 2 Pi`, which allows the `Conditional` expressions to be eliminated.

```
Plot[{ArcTan[(600 - z), 155], ArcTan[(100 - z), 155]}, {z, 0, 750}]
```

[image]

Then the Integrals can be performed as follows:

```
Assuming[2 Pi > x2 > x1 > 0, With[{A = 1/137, B = 1, p = 100}, 
    Integrate[π A^2 (1 - (B^2) (Sin[x/2])^2) (Sin[x])/
        (2 (p^2) (B^2) (Sin[x/2])^4), {x, x1, x2}]]]
(* (1/187690000)π (Csc[x1/2]^2 (1 + Log[Sin[x1/2]] - Cos[x1] Log[Sin[x1/2]]) + 
        Csc[x2/2]^2 (-1 - Log[Sin[x2/2]] + Cos[x2] Log[Sin[x2/2]])) *)
% /. {x1 -> ArcTan[(600 - z), 155], x2 -> ArcTan[(100 - z), 155]};
Integrate[%, {z, 0, 750}]/700
% /. {%[[3, -1]] -> (%[[3, -1]] //FullSimplify), %[[3, -2]] -> (%[[3, -2]] //FullSimplify)}
(* (1/131383000000)π (-(1500000/961) - (28025 Sqrt[1361])/2883 - (33025 Sqrt[1861])/2883 + 
   (168025 Sqrt[15361])/2883 + (193025 Sqrt[17861])/2883 + 100 ArcSinh[20/31] - 
   600 ArcSinh[30/31] - 600 ArcSinh[120/31] + 100 ArcSinh[130/31] - 155 ArcTan[31/130] + 
   155 ArcTan[31/120] + 155 ArcTan[31/30] - 155 ArcTan[31/20] + 250 Log[25] - 
   825 Log[1861] + 1075 Log[17861] + 50 Log[34025] - 300 Log[384025] + 
   750 Log[3722 (30 + Sqrt[1861])] - 750 Log[35722 (130 + Sqrt[17861])]) *)
%3 // N 
(* 2.72033*10^-7 *)
```

(`FullSimplify` is applied only to the last two terms of the output of the second `Integrate`, because applying it to the entire expression is very slow and produces an undesirable expression.)